# Crashlytics distribution failed body too long

Tags: android, jenkins, crashlytics

I am having problem while uploading build to Crashlytics using Jenkins.

Here is my ant build command looks so far.

```
ant -file build.xml -DbetaDistributionGroupAliases=android-beta-testers -DbetaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath=/opt/jenkins/workspace/staging-mobile-android/change_log.txt -Dkey.store=/var/lib/jenkins/Test.keystore -Dkey.store.password=testpassword -Dkey.alias=testkeystore
```

I am contentiously receiving following error message.

```
crashlytics-upload-distribution:
     [echo] Uploading /opt/jenkins/workspace/staging-mobile-android/Test/bin/Test-release.apk to Crashlytics...
     [java]  WARN - Crashlytics had a problem uploading the distribution. Validation failed: Body is too long (maximum is 16384 characters)
     [java] Exception in thread "main" com.crashlytics.tools.android.exception.PluginException: Distribution upload failed.
     [java]     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:533)
     [java]     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processArgs(DeveloperTools.java:280)
     [java]     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.main(DeveloperTools.java:251)
     [java] Caused by: com.crashlytics.tools.android.exception.DistributionException: Crashlytics halted compilation because it had a problem uploading the distribution.Validation failed: Body is too long (maximum is 16384 characters)
     [java]     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DistributionTasks.uploadDistribution(DistributionTasks.java:91)
     [java]     at com.crashlytics.tools.android.DeveloperTools.processProperties(DeveloperTools.java:531)
     [java]     ... 2 more
```

Comment: I would guess that your changelog is longer than 16384 characters, and Crashlytics imposes an arbitrarily-low limit on its length.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I deleted some text from changelog and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Alex from Fabric here. Christopher's right that you're hitting the 16384 character limit on Beta release notes. Once you decrease your release notes length below 16384, you'll be all set.

Comment: Thanks Alex, this also helped me