# Crashlytics halted compilation: Body is too long

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric, fabric-beta

I am trying to upload my release notes to Fabric Beta using fastlane's crashlytics method. I am getting the following error:

Crashlytics halted compilation because it had a problem uploading the distribution.Validation failed: Body is too long (maximum is 16384 characters)

Is there any way that i can extend the maximum body length, beyond 16384, or i am stuck with this value ?

I saw the other post related to this issue and i wanted to comment to it but i do not have the required 'reputation' to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crashlytics distribution failed body too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840780/crashlytics-distribution-failed-body-too-long)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This will likely be closed as a duplicate of the other question due to the similarity. There is not a way to change the maximum body length.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much!